# WordPress PHP if not equal to but if greater than

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site where I am trying to dynamically create a comma separated list of values using PHP. However all of my lists have a comma at the end when they shouldn't and I can't seem to work out how to remove it.

My current code is;

```
$tcount=count($terms);
foreach($terms as $term){
    echo $term->name;
    if($tcount>1){
        echo ', ';
    }
}
```

There is a comma at the end where it should simply be blank. I tried the following code instead but it didn't work;

```
$tcount=count($terms);
foreach($terms as $term){
    echo $term->name;
    if(!$tcount==$tcount && $tcount>1){
        echo ', ';
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trim the last comma:

```
$result = "";

$tcount=count($terms);
foreach($terms as $term) {
  // save output in temporary variable...
  $result .= $term->name;
  $result .= ', ';
}
echo substr($result, 0, -2);  // delete last two characters (", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd use `rtrim()`

Like this:

```
rtrim($string, ',');
```

[`Example`](http://codepad.org/durzwg6R)

Comment: `rtrim()` for sure looks cleaner than my approach (`substr()`), but it won't work for OP's output string, take a look [here](http://codepad.org/agrV1SNF). It should be `rtrim($string, ', ')`, with space added. However, this will trim also last name, if it ends with comma - although this is unlikely, it's a little hidden side-effect that may be difficult to spot.

Comment: @MichałRybak good spot, I was going to go with the `substr()` way but thought OP wanted quick and clean, thank you for pointing out the rest!

Answer (score 0):

you should try php's inbuilt function.

it will minimize the code and also the precise way

```
$output = array();
foreach($terms as $term){
  $output[] = $term->name;
}
echo implode(', ', $output);
```

thanks